# How to set status bar color in android

Tags: android, statusbar

I have used this below code to set the status bar color. placed this code under values-v21  folder

`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#263143</item>

<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

</style>
```

`
But it makes following 
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
How to solve this?

Comment: Show your `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 1):

You should drop `android` prefix from `android:colorPrimaryDark`

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#263143</item>
```

> We now use the support implementation of Toolbar/ActionBar on all platforms meaning that we no longer read any `android: attributes` related to the action bar.

Source: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#theming

Also, `Theme.Material` is only available from API 21. If you want it work on lower APIs, use `AppCompat` themes instead.

> The material theme is only available in Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above. The v7 Support Libraries provide themes with material design styles for some widgets and support for customizing the color palette.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Answer (score 0):

StatusBar doesn't work for devices with API level less than 21. If your min API level is less than that then you have to do some change in your java source file. Go to the source file to which you want to add the status bar color. Then wrap the `OnCreate()` method with annotation `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)`.

Then inside the method you have to check whether the device is capable or not as shown below.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
 window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Statusbar));
    }
```